# Как использовать Markdown-файлы из репозитория для генерации Wiki на GitHub?

Tags: github

Имеется приватный/частный репозиторий на GitHub. В папке решения (solution в Visual Studio), которое представляет репозиторий,имеется файл без расширения README, который "подхватывается" GitHub'ом для использования в качестве начальной страницы репозитория. На GitHub'e имеется Wiki, которая, [согласно документации](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages#cloning-wikis-to-your-computer), может быть склонирована следующей командой

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.wiki.git
```

Но в этом случае создаётся отдельный репозиторий. Получается, что код отдельно, Wiki отдельно. Отсюда возник вопрос:
каким образом использовать файлы Markdown, находящиеся непосредственно в папке решения, для Wiki GitHub'a?
На мой взгляд удобно видеть изменения файлов проекта из одного места, а не отдельных репозиториев. Может быть имеются какие-то общепринятые практики? Сейчас на ум приходит лишь добавление ссылок в README, которые вели бы на Markdown-файлы находящиеся в подпаке решения docs, но в этом случае весь функционал (оглавление, ссылки и т.д.) Wiki от GitHub'a отваливается.

*Предвидя предложения использования сторонних сервисов генерации документации, обращу внимание на то, что репозиторий приватный/частный.*

Comment: Можно попробовать как-то через github actions настроить, чтобы изменения синхронизировались между основным репозиторием и вики.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365) - использовать [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) для синхронизации [GitHub Wiki](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/documenting-your-project-with-wikis) с определённой директорией репозитория.

В маркетплейсе GitHub'a имеется несколько actions для синхронизации Wiki репозитория и определённой директории, но после нескольких проб я выбрал [GitHub Wiki Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-wiki-action). Итак:

- в [настройках аккаунта](https://github.com/settings/tokens) GitHub создаём новый токен и даём ему описательное имя. После генерации токена Вы должны его сохранить, т.к. второй раз его увидеть невозможно;
- в настройках репозитория (https://github.com/UserName/RepoName/settings/secrets/actions) добавляем [секретные переменные](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) для используемых действий:

  - `GH_TOKEN` для частного репозитория со значением сохранённого на первом шаге токена
  - `GH_MAIL` эл.адрес "ассоциированного" с токеном пользователя (что бы это не значило)
- добавляем действие в настройках репозитория

```yml
name: Deploy Wiki

on:
  push:
    paths:
      # Trigger only when wiki directory changes
      - 'docs/wiki/**'
    branches:
      # And only on master branch
      - master

jobs:
  deploy-wiki:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Push Wiki Changes
      uses: Andrew-Chen-Wang/github-wiki-action@v2
      env:
        # Make sure you have that / at the end. We use rsync 
        # WIKI_DIR's default is wiki/
        WIKI_DIR: docs/wiki/
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
        GH_MAIL: ${{ secrets.GH_MAIL }}
        GH_NAME: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
```

> Обратите внимание, что в примере конфигурационного файла на странице описания action приводится недопустимое имя секрета `GITHUB_TOKEN`, т.к. согласно [документации](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets) имя секрета не может начинаться с префикса `GITHUB_` и при попытке создания такой переменной Вы получите ошибку о недопустимости такого имени. Другими словами: если репозиторий публичный, то нужно использовать предопределённый секрет `GITHUB_TOKEN`, если же репозиторий частный, то необходимо создать секрет самому
> *(поправьте меня знатоки GitHub'a если я не прав, но на данный момент я понимаю это так)*.

[Список](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-wiki-action#inputs) всех используемых переменных.

Comment: Отлично, не знал что готовые решения для этого есть